# laravel brainsocket websocket

Tags: php, laravel, websocket

I am trying to make a chat web app using php and websockets.
I ran into Laravel's BrainSocket Websocket and I'm having a good start.

However I'm wondering, is it possible for me to emit an event from the server to a specified client?

What Im trying to achieve is to notify the user that his/her chatmate has sent a reply.

Comment: I'm wondering if you already found an answer on this question yourself ? I've got the same question.

Comment: @JoeriShoeby Not really. I found out that this is not possible with php sockets. However feel free to browse socket.io using nodejs.

Comment: This is possible using socket.io and node?

Comment: @JoeriShoeby Yes absolutely!

Comment: Okay, thanks for you time and knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can send reply for particular user.You can sent reply with Handshake client Id. Every handshake will make a client handshake id.

Comment: Can you please clarify? This seemed vague to me. Or could you at least provide some psuedo codes?

Comment: https://github.com/gonzalo123/RealTimeMonitor this link will help You.. it is web socket using php

Comment: I will be giving that one a look. Thanks

Comment: From what I have understood, this is used for realtime error logging.